# Solving Poisson's equation with Quantum Fourier Transform

Tags: qiskit

I found Quantum Fourier Transform in the [Qiskit textbook](https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-algorithms/quantum-fourier-transform.html), but I'm looking specifically for how to solve Poisson's equation with the Quantum Fourier transform.

Are there any references that talk about how to do this?

Comment: I found this article which seems to answer your question: https://docs.lib.purdue.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=2327&context=nanopub

Comment: @Winona thank you. Maybe, do you know has qiskit already realised(solved) mathematical physics equations(Laplace's equation or other)?

Comment: It looks like the answer is already here: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/14155/solving-mathematical-physics-equations-with-quantum-fourier-transform. There is an algorithm HHL and VQLS that solves systems of linear equations, the Quantum Fourier Transform and Quantum Phase Estimation (used in HHL). More algorithms are in the module qiskit.aqua.algorithms.