# Solving mathematical physics equations with Quantum Fourier Transform

Tags: qiskit

Has qiskit already realised(solved) mathematical physics equations? For example, Laplace's equation,Poisson's equation or other? if it is yes, where can i find it?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Qiskit have what you are asking for. They have this community tutorial page that can be useful if you don't know about it already: https://github.com/qiskit-community/qiskit-community-tutorials

---

**On the side note about QFT:**

Although Quantum Fourier Transform, which is exactly identical to Discrete Fourier Transform, can be implemented efficiently on a quantum computer. An exponential speed up comparing to the classical Fast Fourier Transform even. It doesn't mean that it will be useful by running it on a quantum computer!

Quantum computing gives us an exponential scaling and a way to do this so efficient, but it also limits us from reading out the output state directly.  That is,

$$QFT: |\psi \rangle \to |\phi \rangle$$

This doesn't mean we can see what $|\phi \rangle$ is since a quantum measurement collapse a wavefunction into one of the eigenstate.

That is why designing quantum algorithm to take advantage of the efficiency of QFT for hard classical problems is no easy task.

Comment: Thank you. I am researching photonic crystals and in this theme a lot of mathematical physics equations. I hope, maybe i can compute some results on real quantum hardware.